# Should I store user profile information in cache or session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

My website has a small menu in the upper right hand corner that says the user's First Name and Last Name.  I put this piece into a partial view.  Since this displays on every page, I obviously think to cache it so I don't have to get the user's information everytime a page loads.  Should I store this in cache or session data and also where should i create my code to cache this data if its in every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per scenarion, you should definitely use cache. and as you said, you already have menu as partial view

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
    public ActionResult mymenu()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is preferred to store user information in session , not in cache. Cache is mostly application level  and Session is per user/session. You can store per user info in the cache, providing you provide a key (either by session or cookie) .

This article might be useful :- [cache-session-viewstate-c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26621/Cache-Session-and-ViewState)

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to the ASP.Net Cache, information stored in it is available to any .Net page running on the machine. I would think in your case the Session would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what authentication mechanism you are using but it may already be stored in:

HttpContext.Current.User

or

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a User object which I set all the handy parameters I need across my site.

This object is stored in the session or database depending on the site